# Time Synced Bokeh span

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

I'm looking to create a span on an HTML Bokeh plot that updates with the current time.  I'm able to create the span and hook it to a slider which will run the function whenever the slider is updated, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Here's the plot:

[image: Example]

And the source:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import Span, CustomJS, Slider, HoverTool
from bokeh.layouts import column
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

y = list(range(0, 61))

today = datetime.today()
one_min = today + timedelta(minutes=1)
x = pd.date_range(start=today, end=one_min, freq="S")


df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})

df["x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["x"])
df.set_index(df["x"], inplace=True)

fig = figure(height=400, width=800, x_axis_type="datetime")
fig.line(
    df.index, df.y, legend_label="Test",
)

span = Span(
    location=df.index[0].timestamp() * 1000,
    dimension="height",
    line_color="red",
    name="timer_span",
)

fig.add_layout(span)

callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(span=span), code="span.location = Date.now()",
)

slider = Slider(
    start=0,
    end=100,
    value=0,
    title="time",
)

slider.js_on_change("value", callback)


fig.add_layout(span)
fig.add_tools(HoverTool())
layout = column(fig, slider)
output_file("Test.html")
save(layout)
```

Ideally, there would just be the plot and the time would be updated via a function, in case the source of the time needed to be changed in the future.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the "now" time once, up-front at the time the plot was generated? Or do you want the span update continuously (moving forward forever)? Something else? What are the exact conditions that should cause the span location to change?

Comment: The latter, the span should always and continuously move forward with the current time.

Comment: I'll be honest: that does not make much sense. In a matter of seconds the original data will be vastly compressed into a tiny region and indecipherable. In any event, there's no JS-only periodic callbacks built in to Bokeh. You can either use a full Bokeh server application, or embed the plot in a page with your own JS to set up `setTimeout` callbacks that update the state.